# plotting a graph with multiple bars in R

Tags: r

I am struggling to plot the following data and think it is because of the format of the data.

```
structure(list(HE_Provider = c("Coventry University", "The University of Leicester", 
"Total"), Bath_and_North_East_Somerset = c(15, 20, 205), Bedford = c(85, 
90, 1040), Blackburn_with_Darwen = c(10, 20, 95), Blackpool = c(10, 
5, 60), `Bournemouth,_Poole_and_Christchurch` = c(35, 15, 285
), Bracknell_Forest = c(15, 10, 210), Buckinghamshire = c(195, 
145, 1835), Cambridgeshire = c(130, 160, 2500), Central_Bedfordshire = c(115, 
70, 1120), Cheshire_East = c(45, 55, 935), Cheshire_West_and_Chester = c(25, 
40, 535), City_of_Bristol = c(40, 35, 390), City_of_Derby = c(65, 
135, 4115), City_of_Kingston_upon_Hull = c(25, 20, 265), City_of_Leicester = c(315, 
1275, 6860), City_of_Nottingham = c(65, 145, 5405), City_of_Plymouth = c(15, 
10, 135), City_of_Portsmouth = c(15, 15, 130), City_of_Southampton = c(15, 
20, 140), `City_of_Stoke-on-Trent` = c(50, 15, 475), City_of_York = c(35, 
20, 350), Cornwall = c(25, 25, 300), County_Durham = c(20, 40, 
330), Cumbria = c(30, 20, 305), Darlington = c(0, 15, 110), Derbyshire = c(100, 
145, 6925), Devon = c(50, 50, 630), Dorset = c(30, 20, 285), 
    East_Riding_of_Yorkshire = c(75, 45, 760), East_Sussex = c(55, 
    50, 650), Essex = c(365, 180, 3320), Gloucestershire = c(150, 
    85, 905), Greater_London = c(5550, 1930, 18285), Greater_Manchester = c(245, 
    280, 2820), Halton = c(5, 10, 80), Hampshire = c(180, 120, 
    1485), Hartlepool = c(5, 10, 55), Herefordshire = c(50, 15, 
    235), Hertfordshire = c(385, 270, 4815), Isle_of_Wight = c(10, 
    5, 90), Isles_of_Scilly = c(0, 0, 0), Kent = c(365, 195, 
    2590), Lancashire = c(75, 125, 985), Leicestershire = c(540, 
    980, 8010), Lincolnshire = c(145, 190, 7710), Luton = c(105, 
    75, 685), Medway = c(95, 35, 425), Merseyside = c(75, 120, 
    975), Middlesbrough = c(10, 5, 65), Milton_Keynes = c(265, 
    170, 2205), Norfolk = c(120, 115, 2410), North_East_Lincolnshire = c(20, 
    10, 810), North_Lincolnshire = c(20, 20, 810), North_Somerset = c(25, 
    15, 205), North_Yorkshire = c(500, 80, 1160), Northamptonshire = c(680, 
    510, 7505), Northumberland = c(10, 25, 235), Nottinghamshire = c(140, 
    185, 9410), Oxfordshire = c(280, 135, 1785), Peterborough = c(85, 
    135, 1560), Reading = c(75, 25, 260), Redcar_and_Cleveland = c(5, 
    5, 90), Rutland = c(5, 35, 345), Shropshire = c(60, 30, 500
    ), Slough = c(95, 40, 270), Somerset = c(40, 40, 490), South_Gloucestershire = c(40, 
    25, 310), South_Yorkshire = c(105, 180, 3220), `Southend-on-Sea` = c(35, 
    25, 345), Staffordshire = c(370, 150, 3825), `Stockton-on-Tees` = c(20, 
    15, 145), Suffolk = c(115, 115, 1935), Surrey = c(195, 155, 
    2900), Swindon = c(50, 25, 225), Telford_and_Wrekin = c(60, 
    20, 360), Thurrock = c(140, 40, 370), Torbay = c(5, 5, 65
    ), Tyne_and_Wear = c(45, 60, 680), Warrington = c(20, 20, 
    290), Warwickshire = c(2080, 210, 2825), West_Berkshire = c(35, 
    25, 300), West_Midlands = c(8315, 915, 8220), West_Sussex = c(105, 
    95, 1115), West_Yorkshire = c(200, 245, 3005), Wiltshire = c(90, 
    55, 630), Windsor_and_Maidenhead = c(40, 25, 405), Wokingham = c(70, 
    35, 395), Worcestershire = c(350, 110, 1350),       `England_(county_unitary_authority_unknown)` = c(0, 
    10, 770), Total_England = c(24990, 11530, 154930), Total = c(25380, 
    11845, 158480)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to plot the Region on the bottom but don't have a title for these regions, with the numbers up the y axis and the fill being the university.

Answer (score 2):

This type of problems generally has to do with reshaping the data. The format should be the long format and the data is in wide format. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) on how to reshape the data from wide to long format.

Reshape the data and plot with `geom_col`.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(tidyr)
  library(ggplot2)
})

df1 %>%
  select(-matches("England"), -matches("Total")) %>%
  pivot_longer(-HE_Provider, names_to = "Region") %>%
  ggplot(aes(Region, value, fill = HE_Provider)) +
  geom_col() +
  theme_bw(base_size = 10) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 7, angle = 75, vjust = 1, hjust = 1),
        legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

We could bring the data in long format. For y we used log scale:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-HE_Provider) %>% 
  group_by(HE_Provider, name) %>% 
  summarise(sum_value = sum(value)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=name, y=log(sum_value), fill=HE_Provider))+
  geom_col(position=position_dodge())+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

[image]